# click event fires immediately in ios webkit before jquery confirmation dialogue displayed

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari

I have a remote link from rails which produces this html

```
<a href="/comments/154/remove" class="delete_event_comment" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

and coffeescript that asks for confirmation

```
  $('.delete_event_comment').click ->
    confirm("Delete Comment: Are you sure?")
```

which is equivalent to this javascript

```
$('.delete_event_comment').click(function() {
  return confirm("Delete Comment: Are you sure?");
});
```

It works as expected on safari on the desktop: first display the dialogue, then either do nothing if the user presses cancel or send the ajax call to delete the comment if the user presses OK

But on the iphone safari it first sends the ajax call and then displays the dialogue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about coffee script but.. I'd try:

```
$('.delete_event_comment').click ->
return confirm("Delete Comment: Are you sure?")
```

Explanation: jQuery click event cuts the link normal action (or propagation) when `false` is returned.

Comment: thanks -- that's not it though. I edited the question and added the javascript equivalent to the coffeescript I initially posted